# Error: Can't locate File/HomeDir.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, latex, indentation

I use a Mac OS X 10.8, and want to run the `latexindent.pl` `perl` script on my latex files. This script is made by https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.plx. When I run this script on a `latexfile` I get this error message:

```
Can't locate File/HomeDir.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at helloworld.pl line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at helloworld.pl line 10.
```

It seems that I am missing the File::HomeDir module in perl so I tried to download it using:

`sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install File::HomeDir`',

I get the following error:

Can't locate object method "install" via package "File::HomeDir".

I managed to install the `YAML::Tiny` package without any problems.

I tried to run:

```
1 #!/usr/bin/perl
2 
3 use strict;
4 use warnings;
5 use FindBin;
6 use YAML::Tiny;
7 use File::Copy;
8 use File::Basename;
9 use Getopt::Std;
10 use File::HomeDir;
11 
12 print "hello world";
13 exit;
```

and got the same Error message as above...

Do anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 22):

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install "File::HomeDir"'
                             ^             ^
```

Comment: or just `sudo cpan -i File::HomeDir`

Comment: or just `sudo cpan File::HomeDir`

Comment: It gives following error: `HASCOMPILERbM3C/TESTkh3J.c:2:10: fatal error: 'EXTERN.h' file not found`

Comment: @alper, Ask as a question.

Comment: @ikegami I am sorry I will ask as a question. It's related to Apple's introduced System Integrity Protection. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52997962/2402577

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem. I just ran these commends, and it worked for me

```sh
sudo cpan -i File::HomeDir
```

then

```sh
sudo cpan -i Unicode::GCString
```

Basically, I will run `latexindent file_name.tex`, then an error message will appear that says `you may need to install the XXXX module` then I install the `XXXX` module using `sudo cpan -i XXXX`

Comment: The `-i` is implied when there are no other switches, so you could simply have `cpan Unicode::GCString`.

Answer (score 5):

I just had this problem with macOS M1.
If you don't want to use sudo, which I would strongly recommend not to.
You can install the formulae `latexindent` via brew:

```
brew install latexindent
```

This fixed my issue without having to use sudo.