# latexindent: trouble installing File::HomeDir, Mac::SystemDirectory since macOS 11 Big Sur

Tags: macos, perl, latex, cpan, macos-big-sur

Before I begin, I should note that I never had this problem on macOS 10.15 Catalina, and the responses in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682304/fatal-error-extern-h-file-not-found-while-installing-perl-modules/52997962) similar thread did not solve the problem, unfortunately.

I'm experimenting with `latexindent` on a fresh install of macOS 11 Big Sur and I'm having issues with `File:HomeDir`: running `latexindent` returns a whole list of errors, beginning with `Can't locate File/HomeDir.pm in @INC`. I've tried using `cpan` to install that module, but I end up with following:

```
Reading '/Users/myname/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 24 Dec 2020 05:41:03 GMT
Running install for module 'File::HomeDir'
Checksum for /Users/myname/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.006.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /Users/myname/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring R/RE/REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.006.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Mac::SystemDirectory 0.04 not found.
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for File::HomeDir
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.006.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for R/RE/REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.006.tar.gz
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----     REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.006.tar.gz    ----
    Mac::SystemDirectory [requires]
Running install for module 'Mac::SystemDirectory'
Checksum for /Users/myname/.cpan/sources/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.13.tar.gz ok
Configuring E/ET/ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.13.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
HASCOMPILERjIOx/TESTn6oE.c:2:10: fatal error: 'EXTERN.h' file not found
#include "EXTERN.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Couldn't execute cc  -g -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector-strong -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -Os "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"   -c HASCOMPILERjIOx/TESTn6oE.c -o HASCOMPILERjIOx/TESTn6oE.o: Inappropriate ioctl for device at Makefile.PL line 14.
Requires a compiler
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
  ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.13.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
  REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.006.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /Users/myname/.cpan/build/File-HomeDir-1.006-2
  REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.006.tar.gz
  Has already been prepared
Running make for R/RE/REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.006.tar.gz
Warning: Prerequisite 'Mac::SystemDirectory => 0.04' for 'REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.006.tar.gz' failed when processing 'ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.13.tar.gz' with 'writemakefile => NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL' returned status 6400'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
cp lib/File/HomeDir/Driver.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/Driver.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/MacOS9.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/MacOS9.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/Darwin/Carbon.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/Darwin/Carbon.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/Darwin/Cocoa.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/Darwin/Cocoa.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/Windows.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/Windows.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/FreeDesktop.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/FreeDesktop.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/Test.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/Test.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/Darwin.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/Darwin.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/Unix.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/Unix.pm
Manifying 10 pod documents
  REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.006.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t xt/*.t
t/01_compile.t ........ 1/11 # Implemented by: File::HomeDir::Darwin
t/01_compile.t ........ ok     
t/02_main.t ........... # $<: 501 -- $(: 20 20 12 61 79 80 81 98 701 33 100 204 250 395 398 399 400
t/02_main.t ........... ok     
t/10_test.t ........... ok     
t/11_darwin.t ......... ok   
t/12_darwin_carbon.t .. skipped: Not running on 32-bit Darwin
t/13_darwin_cocoa.t ... skipped: Not running on Darwin with Cocoa API using Mac::SystemDirectory
t/20_empty_home.t ..... ok   
All tests successful.
Files=7, Tests=90,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.01 sys +  0.48 cusr  0.13 csys =  0.66 CPU)
Result: PASS
  REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.006.tar.gz
Tests succeeded but one dependency not OK (Mac::SystemDirectory)
  REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.006.tar.gz
  [dependencies] -- NA
Failed during this command:
 ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.13.tar.gz        : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL' returned status 6400
 REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.006.tar.gz            : make_test NO one dependency not OK (Mac::SystemDirectory)
```

I really don't know much about perl, but it seems to me that `Mac::SystemDirectory` is missing, When I try to install that, however, I get

```
Reading '/Users/myname/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 24 Dec 2020 05:41:03 GMT
Running install for module 'Mac::SystemDirectory'
Checksum for /Users/myname/.cpan/sources/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.13.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /Users/myname/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring E/ET/ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.13.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
HASCOMPILER5Emh/TESTS3W7.c:2:10: fatal error: 'EXTERN.h' file not found
#include "EXTERN.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Couldn't execute cc  -g -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector-strong -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -Os "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"   -c HASCOMPILER5Emh/TESTS3W7.c -o HASCOMPILER5Emh/TESTS3W7.o: Inappropriate ioctl for device at Makefile.PL line 14.
Requires a compiler
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
  ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.13.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.13.tar.gz        : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL' returned status 6400
```

From this it seems that a header file `EXTERN.h` is missing, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions? My apologies for the huge blocks of code - I figured it would be better to include all possible details. Thanks a lot!

Note: I posted this [same question in the LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576232/latexindent-trouble-installing-filehomedir-macsystemdirectory-since-macos), but figured I would also ask here since it seems to be a broader perl issue.

Comment: `EXTERN.h` is part of Perl. But your distro (Apple) might have withheld its inclusion. Maybe there's a package you need to install?

Comment: There are problems building modules that try to link to external libraries right now on Big Sur, but this doesn't seem related.

Comment: Which version of `perl` are you using? Type `which perl; perl --version`. If you are using the system perl, maybe you could try install perl 5.32 using perlbrew? I think then you will get the `EXTERN.h` header

Comment: Seems like it is `ExtUtils::HasCompiler` that fails, I have added an [issue](https://github.com/Leont/extutils-hascompiler/issues/13) at their issue tracker

Comment: A temporary fix seems to be to set the include search path explicitly: `export CPATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE:$CPATH` and then run `sudo cpan Mac::SystemDirectory`

Comment: Håkon, thanks for all of your thoughts. Looks like I'm running v5.28.2 right now. While the missing header is certainly in the directory you pointed to, I'm still getting the same error after setting the new path.

Comment: SOLVED: After adding to `CPATH`, installing `Mac::SystemDirectory` worked from the cpan _shell_. I have no idea why it didn't work in the one liner, but regardless this solved the problem. Thanks a lot Håkon!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Fatal error: 'EXTERN.h' file not found" while installing Perl modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682304/fatal-error-extern-h-file-not-found-while-installing-perl-modules)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To summarize the solution that worked for me: the issue is the header file `EXTERN.h` isn't on the `CPATH` by default in macOS 11 Big Sur. To fix this, add the directory containing `EXTERN.h` to `CPATH`:

```sh
export CPATH=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE:$CPATH
```

Then open the `cpan` shell (just type `cpan` then enter into the command line) and type `install Mac::SystemDirectory`. After this process finished I was able to install `File:HomeDir` as well, and some other modules, to get `latexindent` working.

Note: I had to set up `cpan` before I did this; just opening the shell and following the instructions was sufficient.

Thanks a lot to [Håkon Hægland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173773/h%c3%a5kon-h%c3%a6gland) for the solution!

Comment: For me, the path `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/` doesn't exist (the only directory inside `CommandLineTools` is `usr/share/man`). I don't know where to go from there. I tried `brew install perl` but it did not create that directory. My `perl --version` is v5.28.2.

Comment: Have you run `xcode-select --install`? I think that should populate the `CommandLineTools` directory.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! I think this got me past this particular issue.

Comment: If the current $CPATH is empty, then this solution will add `.` to the default include paths. This can cause issues elsewhere, such as [VSCode's C++ extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/9079). The version in this answer is also no longer included in the latest version of macOS. An updated and fixed version would be `export CPATH="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE${CPATH:+:${CPATH}}"`