# perl : trouble installing File::HomeDir on macOS 11 Big Sur

Tags: perl

I use LaTeX to write papers, and latexindent works very well on macOS Catalina.
But when I updated macOS to Big Sur, latexindent can't work anymore, prompting `Can't locate File/HomeDir.pm in @INC.`
So I used `cpan` to install the module according to the prompt, and it says `fatal error: 'EXTERN.h' file not found`.

I used stackoverflow to search the ways to figure it out, and I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65435551/latexindent-trouble-installing-filehomedir-macsystemdirectory-since-macos?noredirect=1&lq=1) is as same as mine.

So I find the directory which contains the header files perl needs on my Mac, and I set `CPATH`. Then I type `sudo cpan` to open the cpan shell, and type `install Mac::SystemDirectory`. and the prompt is as follows:

```sh
Reading '/Users/myname/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 18 Mar 2021 01:56:22 GMT
Running install for module 'Mac::SystemDirectory'
Checksum for /Users/myname/.cpan/sources/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.13.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /Users/myname/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Configuring E/ET/ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.13.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
HASCOMPILERdZv0/TESTgu8P.c:2:10: fatal error: 'EXTERN.h' file not found
#include "EXTERN.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Couldn't execute cc  -g -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector-strong -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -Os "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"   -c HASCOMPILERdZv0/TESTgu8P.c -o HASCOMPILERdZv0/TESTgu8P.o: Inappropriate ioctl for device at Makefile.PL line 14.
Requires a compiler
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
  ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.13.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.13.tar.gz        : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL' returned status 6400
```

It seems CPATH not working. I also tried to copy all the header files in the CORE directory corresponding to `CPATH` to the `/System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE` directory, but even if I used the `sudo` command, it still failed, I don't know why.

So although I set `$CPATH`, judging from the above error output, the compiler did not use the `$CPATH` environment variable but still went to the `/System/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE` directory to look for the header file.

I want to know why this is and how to solve this problem.

PS: I know somebody set CPATH to solve the question, but it did not work for me.

`~/.cpan`'s owner is `root` instead of me.
The first time I use `cpan` to install some modules(without `root`), it said `You do not have write permission for Perl library directories.`, and it asked me which approach I want, I chose `local::lib`，and I can successfully install `Mac::SystemDirectory`
But later when I installed `File::HomeDir`, it said

```
ERROR: Can't create '/Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Mac'
mkdir /Library/Perl/5.28/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Mac: Permission denied at /System/Library/Perl/5.28/ExtUtils/Install.pm line 489.
```

So I just remove `~/.cpan` and I choose `root` now.

Solution: I just delete directory `~/perl5` and `~/.cpan`, reboot my Mac. And I type `cpan install <some_module>`(without root), cpan asked me to choose the approach I want, this time I chose `sudo` and type my root password, and It worked! BTW, if used `sudo` to run some command, it means let the superuser `root` run this command, and root's environment variable is not same as yours, that is the reason why I set the `CPATH` and run `sudo cpan ...` but not working!

Comment: *"sudo cpan"* Did you set CPATH for root user or for your regular user?

Comment: If I don't use "sudo", then `Couldn't mkdir '/Users/myname/.cpan/build/tmp-70881': Permission denied`

Comment: *"Couldn't mkdir ..."* : This happens if you run `cpan Mac::SystemDirectory` (note: not sudo in front of cpan) from the shell prompt?

Comment: Yes, If I add `sudo` before `cpan install Mac::SystemDirectory` ,then I will get `fatal error: 'EXTERN.h' file not found`

Comment: Seems like somehow your `.cpan` directory has gotten the  wrong access permissions ? What is the output of `ls -ld ~/.cpan` ? (It should be owned by you and not root user)

Comment: You can also run the command `stat -f '%Su' ~/.cpan` to get the user ID of the directory

Comment: Re "*If I don't use "sudo",*" HH didn't say don't use `sudo`; they suggesting forcing sudo to inherit the `CPATH` or setting `CPATH` *after* using `sudo`. e.g. `sudo bash -l`, then `export CPATH=...`, then `cpan ...`

Comment: *"So I just remove ~/.cpan and I choose root now."* Were you able to set `CPATH` for root user also?

Comment: I just delete `~/perl5` and `~/.cpan`, reboot my MAC and I type `cpan install ..`, then I chose `sudo` instead of `local::lib`. `cpan` asked me to input my password , and it worked this time! Thanks a lot!  @Håkon @ikegami