# Unable to run latexindent macOS Monterey 12.0.1

Tags: encoding, homebrew, macos-monterey, tex-live, perl5.34

I need to be able to run the command `latexindent` but I get this error every time:

```
Unknown PerlIO layer 'encoding' at /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/Document.pm line 21.
Unknown PerlIO layer "encoding" at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/5.34.0/open.pm line 126.
Unknown PerlIO layer "encoding" at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/5.34.0/open.pm line 134.
Unknown PerlIO layer "encoding" at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/perl/5.34.0/lib/perl5/5.34.0/open.pm line 135.
Attempt to reload PerlIO/encoding.pm aborted.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/FileExtension.pm line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/FileExtension.pm line 20.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/Document.pm line 29.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/Document.pm line 29.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin/latexindent line 27.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin/latexindent line 27.
```

I installed MacTeX with Homebrew through this command `brew install --cask mactex`. When I type the command `which latexindent` it gives this `/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/universal-darwin/latexindent`. I have Perl v5.34.0 and it is here `/opt/homebrew/bin/perl`.

How do I set the encoding for PerlIO?

Answer (score 9):

I solved by installing latexindent via homebrew.
The command is `brew install latexindent`.
I'm on MacOS Monterey 12.4

EDIT: Tested recently on macOS Sonoma 14.4 and it is still working!

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66686306/perl-trouble-installing-filehomedir-on-macos-11-big-sur?noredirect=1&lq=1), I found a solution to my problem like this :

1. I deleted : `~/perl5`, `~/.cpan`, `~/.cpanm`;
2. I restarted my computer;
3. Then I installed `Log::Log4perl` with the command `cpan install Log::Log4perl`. There it asked me if I wanted to choose automatic or
   manual configuration mode.  I chose the automatic mode;
4. Then I installed other modules based on [this
   post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445521/latexindent-cant-locate-log-log4perl-pm-in-inc-you-may-need-to-install-the-l/521463#521463):
   `SQL::Statement`, `Text::CSV_XS`,`DBD::CSV`, `Log::Dispatch::File`, `cpan install YAML::Tiny`, `File::HomeDir`, `Unicode::GCString`, `Mac::SystemDirectory`;

And finally the command `latexindent --version` gives me the version `3.9.1, 2021-03-21` and it works.

Comment: Log4perl no longer required :)